# JavaScript Interface to a Browser not working in 4.2.2

Tags: android, webview

I had tested my javascript interface working perfectly in android 2.3,4.0,4.1 devices
but not working in galaxy S4 which is 4.2.2
i tried calling my native interface from index.html
onload but it says object undefined.

i am calling this function from browser

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.jsinterface.getSomeString("testing from index.html");
}
```

this line of code in my activity for recieving data

```
final class JavaScriptInterface {
    JavaScriptInterface() {}

    public void getSomeString(String data) {
        Log.d("yahoo", "DAta" + data);
        Toast.makeText(Testing.this, "getsomestring:"+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

any suggestion for sending data from browser except this method would also be helpful for me.
or guide me what to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `android:targetSdkVersion` is set to 17 or higher, you need to add the `@JavascriptInterface` annotation to `getSomeData()`, as is described [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).