# WebView.addJavascriptInterface not working

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-webview, webviewclient

I need to call my java function from the web response:

Here is my code please point where am I going wrong

**Activity:**

```
    @InjectView(R.id.loadCardWebView)
android.webkit.WebView webView;

WebViewClient webViewClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(activity), "XYZ");
    initWebViewClient();
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/response.html");

}

private void initWebViewClient() {
    webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
        private int webViewPreviousState;
        private final int STARTED = 1;
        private final int REDIRECTED = 4;

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view,
                                                String urlNewString) {
            webViewPreviousState = REDIRECTED;
            webView.loadUrl(urlNewString);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            webViewPreviousState = STARTED;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {

            if (webViewPreviousState == STARTED) {
                Log.e(TAG ,RESPONSE URL : " + url);
            }

        }
    };
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
}
```

**MY JAVASCRIPT CLASS:**

```
public class JSInterface {
private Activity activity;

public JSInterface(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String string){
    Log.e("REACHED","HERE");
    Timber.e("REACHED HERE");
}
```

}

**AND THIS IS A SAMPLE HTML FILE :**

```
    <html>
<body>
    <a href="test_2.html" target="_blank">goto test 2</a>
    <input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        XYZ.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The show method function never gets call. I get a response from the server which holds the similar code to invoke one function from my javascript class.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532224/javascript-interface-to-a-browser-not-working-in-4-2-2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298664/javascript-interface-not-working-in-my-android-application

Comment: Please don't call loadUrl from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` as it is called for subframes with non-https schemes. If you go to a a page like http://jsbin.com/gupug/1/quiet your code will end up calling view.loadUrl('tel:1234') and you will end up showing an error page, since the webview doesn't know how to load a tel: URL.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what `Timber.e()` is, but is your code actually trying to show a toast message? Maybe it should be more like...

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String string) {
    Toast.makeText(...);
    Log.e("REACHED","HERE");
    Timber.e("REACHED HERE");
}
```